# Is there a more OCaml-esque way to convert a tuple list to list than what I did?

Tags: list, functional-programming, tuples, ocaml

My goal here was to convert a `(int * int) list` to an `int list`. This is what I did:

```
let tuples_list_to_list l =
  let rec aux_tuples_to_list acc l =
    match l with
    | [] -> acc
    | x :: tl -> aux_tuples_to_list (fst x :: snd x :: acc) tl in
  aux_tuples_to_list [] l
```

I was wondering if there was a more "elegant" even though this is subjective or at least better, way to write my function. I was thinking about using `List.map` or `List.fold_left` but I was having issues figuring out I could use those two functions to do the same thing I did. Basically, I think it would be possible to have a one-liner instead of the whole function I wrote.

What do you think? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This task is suited for `List.concat_map` (also known as "flat map" in some other languages):

```
(* List.concat_map : ('a -> 'b list) -> 'a list -> 'b list *)

let tuples_list_to_list l = 
  List.concat_map (fun (x, y) -> [x; y]) l
```

You can use `List.fold_left`, but you'll have to reverse the result at the end as the list is constructed in reverse order:

```
let tuples_list_to_list l = 
  List.rev (List.fold_left (fun acc (x, y) -> y :: x :: acc) [] l)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also deconstruct the tuple values in the pattern matching instead of using `fst` and `snd` (This version, unlike yours, gives a result list with the numbers in the same order as the orignal):

```ml
let tuples_list_to_list l =
  let rec aux_tuples_to_list acc l =
    match l with
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | (x, y) :: tl -> aux_tuples_to_list (y :: x :: acc) tl in
  aux_tuples_to_list [] l
```

Yet Another Option is using `List.fold_right`, which avoids the need to reverse the accumulator list at the end at the cost of not being tail recursive:

```ml
let tuples_list_to_list l =
  List.fold_right (fun (x, y) acc -> x :: y :: acc) l [];;
```

Comment: Pattern-matching the elements out of the tuple is _definitely_ more idiomatic than using `fst` and `snd` in OCaml.